# max() not returning the correct maximum number

Tags: python, floating-point

I am using the following code to find out which of the two numbers has a maximum value:

```
maximum = max(2.3,2.300000000001) 
print maximum
```

But the output I get is `2.3` and not `2.300000000001`. Can anyone explain why this happens?

Comment: The output you get is 2.300000000001. `print` rounds it for you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is floating point math broken?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: Good explanation here [Floating Point Arithmetic: Issues and Limitations](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html) about why the print function truncates float values.

Comment: use repr() its built in function in python

Answer (score 7):

Don't worry - `max` isn't broken, and `maximum` indeed holds `2.300000000001`. `print`, however, rounds it when printing. You could use [`repr`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#func-repr) to prove that:

```
>>> maximum = max(2.3,2.300000000001) 
>>> print maximum
2.3
>>> print repr(maximum)
2.300000000001
```

Answer (score 4):

From [the doc](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html):

> **14. Floating Point Arithmetic: Issues and Limitations**
>
> It’s easy to forget that the stored value is an approximation to the
>   original decimal fraction, because of the way that floats are
>   displayed at the interpreter prompt. Python only prints a decimal
>   approximation to the true decimal value of the binary approximation
>   stored by the machine. If Python were to print the true decimal value
>   of the binary approximation stored for 0.1, it would have to display
>
> `>>> 0.1`
>
> `0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625`
>
> That is more digits than most people find useful, so Python keeps the
>   number of digits manageable by displaying a rounded value instead
>
> `>>> 0.1`
>
> `0.1`

Answer: result you get is fine, but `print` rounds it.

You can check the actual value with [repr()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#func-repr):

```
maximum = max(2.3,2.300000000001) 
print repr(maximum)
```

Answer (score 1):

The Python print command truncates numbers automatically. There's some explanations in the comments above. If you want it to print the full value, try using `print "%13f" % maximum` to show you the full value

Answer (score 1):

In your case, as said by mureinik, only print was the cause of the problem. A more direct demonstration is :

```
>>> a = 2.300000000001
>>> a
2.300000000001
>>> print(a)
2.3
```

But beware, Python uses underlying floating point of its platform and it has not an inifinite accuracy. As a rule of thumb, only 16 decimal digits are accurate:

```
>>> b = 2.300000000000000001
>>> b
2.3
>>> c = 2.3
>>> b == c
True
```

Answer (score 0):

The "absolute or relative difference" check is implemented by code equivalent to the following Python code:(https://code.google.com/codejam/apactest/faq.html#case_1)

```
def IsApproximatelyEqual(x, y, epsilon):
  """Returns True iff y is within relative or absolute 'epsilon' of x.

  By default, 'epsilon' is 1e-6.
  """
  # Check absolute precision.
  if -epsilon <= x - y <= epsilon:
    return True

  # Is x or y too close to zero?
  if -epsilon <= x <= epsilon or -epsilon <= y <= epsilon:
    return False

  # Check relative precision.
  return (-epsilon <= (x - y) / x <= epsilon
       or -epsilon <= (x - y) / y <= epsilon)
```

It would be good to check this thing as well. 
When python comes out with output, there is some range of ignorance when dealing with real numbers.